# export sqoop with --input-lines-terminated-by=":" not working

Tags: mysql, sqoop, cloudera

I'm trying to export from hdfs to mysql a file that have ":" as line terminator. My sqoop command export only the first row. 
My expected result is to write table test with two columns id and description.Help me please.
Thank you.

In the file file/departments_enclosedby/part-m-00000-test:

```
'2'~'fitness new':'3'~'footwear':'4'~'Apparel':'5'~'Golf':'6'~'Outdoors':'7'~'Fan Shop':'2'~'fitness new':'3'~'footwear':'12'~'Mathematics':'13'~'Science':'14'~'engineering  ':'1000'~'management':'9999'~'\'Data Science\'':
```

My command:

```
sqoop export \
    --connect="jdbc:mysql://***********" \
    --username=********* \
    --password=******* \
    --table=test \
    -m 1 \
    --export-dir="file/departments_enclosedby/part-m-00000-test" \
    --input-enclosed-by="'" \
    --input-escaped-by="\\" \
    --input-fields-terminated-by="~" \
    --input-lines-terminated-by=":"
```

This command ends with:Exported 1 records.

I tried to add a row in the file in this way:

```
'2'~'fitness new':'3'~'footwear':'4'~'Apparel':'5'~'Golf':'6'~'Outdoors':'7'~'Fan Shop':'2'~'fitness new':'3'~'footwear':'12'~'Mathematics':'13'~'Science':'14'~'engineering  ':'1000'~'management':'9999'~'\'Data Science\'':
'3'~'footwear':'4'~'Apparel':'5'~'Golf':'6'~'Outdoors':'7'~'Fan Shop':'2'~'fitness new':'3'~'footwear':'12'~'Mathematics':'13'~'Science':'14'~'engineering  ':'1000'~'management':'9999'~'\'Data Science\'':
```

With this file, sqoop command exports 2 rows, id 2 and 3.

Comment: I have marked your samples as code with <!-- language: lang-none --> to by more readable

Comment: Thank you!! I underline that export is ok for id 1: script sqoop exports column 2 and "fitness new" of orginal file.

Comment: what is the output you are getting in mysql, what is the schema of the mysql table

Comment: The export is only 2, fitness new in mysql table "test". The schema of table test is: id, description. The export with test file is two rows: 2, fitness new and 3, footwear.

Comment: The argument --input-fields-terminated-by 'any delimiter in single quotes' works.

Comment: --input-fields-terminated-by works but --input-lines-terminated-by=":" is not working fine!!! why?

Answer (score 0):

My version of hive doesn't support lines terminator different from \n.

SemanticException 7:20 LINES TERMINATED BY only supports newline '\n' right now. Error encountered near token '-'

So the import works fine but the file can not be read by hive or exported again.

Bye and thank you